# reloading page restarts expired session

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cflogin

I have created a ColdFusion login page and Application.cfc file.  It seems to work fine but I found a bug or hole that I cannot seem to fix.

Its a three page form: The login page; a lookup page with date selection and other questions; and an output page. The user logs in and is authenticated.  If the session expires on the lookup page, the user is routed back to the login page when they try to submit a query.  However, if the session expires they can circumvent the login page by just refreshing the lookup page.

How can I prevent this?  What do I have wrong in my code?  I'd like any refresh of that lookup page to also direct them to the login page.

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset This.name = "TEST_login">
    <cfset This.Sessionmanagement="True">
    <cfset This.loginstorage="session">
    <cfset This.sessionTimeout= CreateTimespan(0,0,1,0) />

    <cferror TYPE="exception" TEMPLATE="error.cfm" MAILTO="email address">

    <cffunction name="onSessionStart">
        <cfset session.loggedIn = false>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="OnRequestStart">
        <cfargument name = "request" required="true"/>

        <cfif IsDefined("Form.logout")>
            <cflogout>
        </cfif>

        <cflogin idletimeout="1200">

            <cfif NOT IsDefined("cflogin")>
                <cfinclude template="acc_hgrant_login.cfm">
                <cfabort>
            <cfelse>
                <cfif cflogin.name IS "" OR cflogin.password IS "">
                    <cfinclude template="acc_hgrant_login2.cfm">
                    <cfabort>
                <cfelse>

                    <cfquery name="loginQuery" dataSource="cfsource">
                        SELECT username, role
                        FROM users
                        WHERE
                            username = '#cflogin.name#'
                            AND password = '#cflogin.password#'
                    </cfquery>

                    <cfif loginQuery.role EQ "admin">
                        <cfloginuser name="#cflogin.name#" Password = "#cflogin.password#"
                            roles="#loginQuery.role#">

                        <cfset Session.isLoggedIn = "Yes">

                    <cfelse>

                        <cfinclude template="login3.cfm">
                        <cfabort>
                    </cfif>

                </cfif>

            </cfif>

        </cflogin>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

On each subsequent page I add

```
 <cfif not isDefined("Session.isLoggedIn")>
```

at top of each page.

However, again, just reloading the 2nd page after a period of time will restart the session even after it expires.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you running after this code runs? `<cfif not isDefined("Session.isLoggedIn")>` that would always return true if the session was expired.

Comment: If not defined it relocates to login page, if defined it just displays the current page.  Its a lookup page with a date selection and few parameters.  I'm sure the issue has to do with reloading the page which seems to reauthenticate and repost the login information.  If time lapse is such that the session has expired I want it to reroute to the login page.   Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description and without being able to see the code of the loaded page, I can only guess at the issue.

I believe a fuller representation of the issue is:

> However, if the session expires they can circumvent the login page by just refreshing the lookup page **and answering yes to "would you like to resubmit the form"**.

The way to fix that is to redirect the page after verifying their credentials and setting their session.  A simple version of this is:

```
                <cfif loginQuery.role EQ "admin">
                    <cfloginuser name="#cflogin.name#" Password = "#cflogin.password#"
                        roles="#loginQuery.role#">

                    <cfset Session.isLoggedIn = "Yes">

                    <cflocation url="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#?#CGI.Query_STRING#" addtoken="false">

                <cfelse>
```

It should be the case that you want to do a `cflocation` at the end of processing every form submission.  The most common counter instance is when asking a user to correct fix validation issues with their form, since a re-post of the form will just reload the validation page; not update databases, etc.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct on the resubmit form option.  I am not using cflocation.  I can change that.  However, on some forms, I do not use cflogin and have home grown security checks using cfldap and other sql checks.  Those forms display sensitive information that I do not like to store in session variables.  If my login checks are on the lookup page, do I have any recourse other than the cflocation approach which would require me to store login info in session variables?

Comment: For example, I have a two page application.  The first page is a simple login page.  The second page takes the login information, checks ldap and once the person's identifier is captured it checks other sql queries and tables for added permission.  The page then displays either bad login or if all checks are passed it will show a page of sensitive information about the individual.  Again the page is secure and the user can shut the browser on exit.  But I would like the page login to expire after a certain amt of time lapses.  What would y suggest I use on this two page application?  Thank you

Comment: Session variables are stored in server memory, so there isn't massive risk of exposure. I tend to only put non sensitive information in the session scope, like the authenticated user id. You could also encrypt the info in the session scope if you were so inclined. In any case, you'll need to cflocation to get the desired effect.

Comment: Ok, one last question.  On my login page that is included if the user is not logged in.  What would I put for the cfform's action?  Since the cflocation directs to the correct page in the application.cfc file, what would you use on the login page?  I originally had the lookup page which is now also in the cflocation tag, but now I keep getting directed right back to the login page.  Its not allowing login.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You have 3 pages.  1. Login form 2. Login form processor 3. Detail page.  1 submits to 2; 2 either `cfinclude`s 1 on error or sets session variables and `cflocation`s to 3 on success. 3 takes session variables, and shows details or `cflocation`s to 1 if issue (e.g. session variable doesn't exist). You need to split your current second page into 2 and 3.

Comment: I have the login form submitting to page 2 (my lookup form) and I used the cflocation tag you entered above in the application.cfc.

Comment: <form action="acc_hgrant_lookup.cfm" method="Post"> on login page and the cflocation tag you included in my application.cfc file.  But the login doesnt work, the url is the lookup page with a question mark in the url but the login page keeps displaying.

Comment: That's because in your Application.cfc you have an if that forces the login page.  You shouldn't be showing the login form if `Session.isLoggedIn` is true.  You should also be locking your session variables.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it to work by scrapping the cflogin and cfc file.  I set up a simple application.cfm file and just looked for session set to yes.  I will go back and try your logic on the cfc file as I figured it was trying to check login each time.  Again thanks for all your assistance.

Comment: The cflocation just doesn't seem to work in the Application.cfc file.  Works great in my application.cfm as I am not using cflogin.  But if a user logins the only check in the cfc file to display the login page is <cfif NOT IsDefined("cflogin")>.  The location tag sends them to lookup page but the lookup page renders the cfc file which again says cflogin doesnt exist?  I thought cflogin would exist throughout the application but it clearly doesn't.  Would it need to be set in a session variable to use the cflocation?

Comment: I don't use `cflogin` maybe the redirect has to happen outside of the `cflogin` closing tag. So you'll set a variable after `cfloginuser` that says a `cflocation` must happen and then check that after the closing `cflogin` tag.

Comment: I just wrapped <cfif Session.loggedIn EQ 'True'> around the cflogin and it seems to be working now.  Set the session to loggedin inside the cflogin and then skip the login check if its still active.  Finally.  You got me on the right path.  I am grateful for your help!